# Topology property of the set of matrices that has an eigenvector orthogonal to a fixed vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Suppose $x \in \mathbb C^n$ is a fixed vector$.$ Define a set
$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal E = \{A \in M_n(\mathbb C): \exists \text{ an eigen-pair }(\lambda, v) \text{ of } A, \text{i.e., }Av = \lambda v \text{ such that } v \perp x \}.
\end{align*}$$

I am trying to see whether $\mathcal E$ is open or closed. I feel this set is closed but cannot prove it.

Comment: It is clear that if $A \in \mathcal {E}$ then $A^n \in \mathcal {E},$ for all $n \geq 0.$

Comment: @Dbchatto67: Sorry I cannot follow. Does this imply the closedness or openness?

Comment: I suspect that you are right about the set being closed.  I would begin by trying to show that
$$
\mathcal E_0 = \{A \in M_n(\Bbb C): \exists v \text{ such that } v \perp x \text{ and } Av = 0\}
$$
is a closed set.  From there, we could characterize your set by
$$
\mathcal E = \{A \in M_n(\Bbb C): \exists \lambda \text{ such that } A - \lambda I \in \mathcal E_0\}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sketch of a proof that your set is closed: first, consider the set
$$
\mathcal E_0 = \{A \in M_n(\Bbb C): \exists v \text{ such that } v \perp x \text{ and } Av = 0\}.
$$
We can see that this set is closed as follows: let $K = \{y : \|y\| = 1, y \perp x\}$. Define $g: M_n(\Bbb C) \to \Bbb R$ by
$$
g(A) = \min_{y \in K} \|Ay\|.
$$
Show that $g$ is a continuous function.  It follows that $\mathcal E_0 = g^{-1}(0)$ is a closed set.  Now, we can consequently conclude that
$$
\mathcal E = \{A \in M_n(\Bbb C): \exists \lambda \text{ such that } A - \lambda I \in \mathcal E_0\}
$$
is a closed set.  One proof that this is so would be as follows: define $h:M_n(\Bbb C) \to \Bbb R$ by
$$
h(A) = \min_{\lambda \in \Bbb C} d(A - \lambda I, \mathcal E_0)
$$
where we define $d(P,\mathcal E_0) = \min\{\|P - Q\|: {Q \in \mathcal E_0}\}$.  Because $h$ is continuous, $\mathcal E = h^{-1}(0)$ is closed.

Comment: I can see that $\mathcal {E_0} \subseteq g^{-1} (0).$ But why should the other inclusion also hold?

Comment: @Dbchatto67: why is $h$ constant $0$? It seems OK to me. Not sure if I am missing something. If $A-\lambda I \notin \mathcal E_0$, then $h \neq 0$. But $A-\lambda I \in \mathcal E_0$ holds only if $Av = \lambda v$ for some $v \perp x$.

Comment: Yeah! You are right. But do you understand why $h^{-1} (0) \subseteq \mathcal {E}$?

Comment: @Dbchatto67: For any $B \in h^{-1}(0)$, there exists some $y_B \in K$ such that $B y_B = 0$. Note by definition of $K$, $y_B \perp x$. This should imply $B \in \mathcal E_0$.

Comment: I think you are trying to say that $B \in g^{-1} (0).$ How do you claim that $\exists$ $y_B \in K$ such that $By_B=0$?

Comment: Suppose that$$\min_{y \in K} \|Ay\|=0.$$ Does it necessarily imply that $\exists$ $y \in K$ such that $Ay = 0?$ That is true only if the set $\{\|A y\|: y \in K \}$ is closed.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. I was thinking $g$. Thinking about it more, I don't quite understand why $h$ can be achieved over $\mathbb C$. Namely, why can we use $\min$ instead of $\inf$.

Comment: For $g$ I think $K$ is compact.

Comment: Exactly that was my point @user43210.

Comment: $K$ is the intersection of a closed subspace (orthogonal to $x$) and the unit sphere in $\mathbb C^n$ if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I asked a follow-up question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3148926/is-the-set-of-matrices-that-has-an-eigenvector-orthogonal-to-a-fixed-vector-zari. Would really appreciate if you can take a look at.