# Is the set of matrices that has an eigenvector orthogonal to a fixed vector Zariski closed?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

This is related to [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3148877/topology-property-of-the-set-of-matrices-that-has-an-eigenvector-orthogonal-to-a?noredirect=1#comment6485917_3148877) I asked.

Suppose $x \in \mathbb C^n$ is a fixed vector$.$ Define a set
$$\begin{align*}
\mathcal E = \{A \in M_n(\mathbb C): \exists \text{ an eigen-pair }(\lambda, v) \text{ of } A, \text{i.e., }Av = \lambda v \text{ such that } v \perp x \}.
\end{align*}$$

It is shown in [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3148906) that $\mathcal E$ is closed in the Euclidean topology. I want to know whether this set is closed in Zariski topology.

Comment: In general, I think the answer is negative. The condition of being “orthogonal complex vectors” cannot be expressed algebraically.

Comment: By “algebraically”, I mean “as the evaluation of a complex polynomial on the entries of a complex vector”.

Comment: @pyon: The role of the orthogonality here is trivial, though; it's just saying $A$ has an eigenvector in some particular subspace of $V$ (which happens to be the orthogonal complement of $x$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  We may assume $x=(0,0,\dots,1)$.  Then $\mathcal{E}$ is the set of $A$ such that there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ such that the matrix formed by the first $n-1$ columns of $\lambda I-A$ has rank less than $n-1$.  This happens for a particular value of $\lambda$ iff all of the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ minors of the first $n-1$ columns of $\lambda I-A$ vanish.  Each of these minors is a polynomial $p_k(A,\lambda)$ in the entries of $A$ and $\lambda$, and we are looking for the set of $A$ such that these polynomials have a common root in $\lambda$.

Let $X_k\subseteq M_n(\mathbb{C})\times \mathbb{C}$ be the vanishing set of the $k$th minor $p_k(A,\lambda)$ (obviously a Zariski closed set).  Then $\mathcal{E}$ is the projection of $\bigcap X_k$ onto $M_n(\mathbb{C})$.  Let $Y_k$ be the Zariski closure of $X_k$ in $M_n(\mathbb{C})\times\mathbb{P}^1$, or equivalently the vanishing set of the polynomial $q_k(A,s,t)=t^dp_k(A,s/t)$ where $d$ is the degree of $p_k$ with respect to $\lambda$ (here $[s:t]$ are the homogeneous coordinates on $\mathbb{P}^1$).  Note that the minor $p_n$ formed by omitting the bottom row is monic in $\lambda$, and so $q_n$ does not vanish at $t=0$ and thus $X_n=Y_n$.  It follows that $\bigcap Y_k=\bigcap X_k$.  But the projection of $\bigcap Y_k$ to $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is Zariski-closed, since the projection $M_n(\mathbb{C})\times\mathbb{P}^1\to M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a closed map in the Zariski topology.  Since $\bigcap Y_k=\bigcap X_k$, this means $\mathcal{E}$ is Zariski-closed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain a little bit why $\mathcal{E}$ is the set of $A$ such that there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ such that the matrix formed by the first $n-1$ columns of $\lambda I-A$ has rank less than $n-1$?

Comment: An element of the kernel of the matrix formed by those first $n-1$ columns is the same thing as an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ whose last entry is $0$.

Comment: I see. Thanks. So the complement of $\mathcal E$ is Zariski open. I confuse myself when thinking about the complement. Is this correct that $\mathcal E^c = \{ A \in M_n(\mathbb C): \forall \text{ eigen-pair } (\lambda, v), \, v \not\perp x\}$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Why is the projection $M_n(\mathbb C) \times \mathbb P^1 \to M_n(\mathbb C)$ closed? Does the conclusion change if replace the field to be $\mathbb R$ where $(\lambda, v)$ is still considered in $\mathbb C$? Thanks. Forgive me if the question is too stupid (I only start on Zariski topology).

Comment: This is a basic theorem in algebraic geometry: for any projective variety $P$ and any variety $V$, the projection $V\times P\to V$ is closed.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{E}$ is still Zariski-closed since you can just use the same polynomials as over $\mathbb{C}$.  (If those polynomials don't have real coefficients, multiply them by their conjugates.)

Comment: Thanks so much.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Why can we assume $x=(0, \dots, 1)$?

Comment: The Zariski topology is invariant under changes of basis, so you can take a change of basis that turns the orthogonal complement of $x$ into the orthogonal complement of $(0,0,\dots,1)$ (assuming $x\neq 0$; if $x=0$ the result is trivial).